# concat two variable and find array value position using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I have array object like this below

```
var TTP01[2,0,0,0,0,0,4,6,1,4,0,9,1]
```

If I assign `TTP01[0]` like this, I will get Output `2`. This is working fine.

But I'm getting values separately and I need to assign the Object.

```
object = TTP;
count  =01;
xy = x*y;
```

I concat like this below

```
var obj = objname.concat(count, "[", xy, "]");
console.log( obj );
```

In console log, I'm getting like this `TTP01[0]`.

But want to get output `2`

Please help me... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work.

```
eval(objname + count)[xy]
```

---

fullcode:

```js
var TTP01 = [2,0,0,0,0,0,4,6,1,4,0,9,1];

var objname = "TTP";
var count = "01";
var xy = 0;

console.log(eval(objname + count)[xy]); // 2
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: TTP012 is not defined

Comment: I added a fullcode. It works on my environment (both node and browser).

Comment: It showing Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: I changed my full code to runnable code snippet, please check it.

Comment: var count = "01"; I'm getting this 01 in variable. But now I'm getting 1. How can I make, 01,02,03...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170038/discussion-between-ashok-charu-and-set0gut1).

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this way,

```js
var TTP01 = [2,0,0,0,0,0,4,6,1,4,0,9,1];
var objname = 'TTP';
var count  = '01';
xy = 0;

var obj = window[objname + count];
console.log( obj[xy] );
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign TTP01 to some base object :

```
 var base = {
   TTP01: [2,0,0,0,0,0,4,6,1,4,0,9,1]
 }


var objname = 'TTP';
var count  = '01';
var objStr = objname + count;
var xy = 0;

console.log(base[objStr][xy])
```